# What is Higgs transition?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, magnetic-monopoles

In recent publications there is a frequent mentioning of the so-called "Higgs transition" in connection with magnetic monoples. Can anybody please describe the phenomenon in simple terms?

For example, it seems that [here](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/08/120807113243.htm) it is claimed that found a material that exhibits magnetic monople superconductivity and can sustain magnetic current.

Does in mean that a cable of such material will have circular electric field around it?